# Reading request content from Java socket InputStream, always hangs after header

Tags: java

I am trying to use core Java to read HTTP request data from an inputstream, using the following code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
```

I receive the header fine, but then the client just hangs forever because the server never finds "EOF" of the request. How do I handle this? I've seen this question asked quite a bit, and most solutions involve something like the above, however it's not working for me. I've tried using both curl and a web browser as the client, just sending a get request

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Where is your code hanging? is `readLine()` not returning?

Comment: Yes it is just getting stuck on readLine() when I step through it in a debugger

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An HTTP request ends with a blank line (optionally followed by request data such as form data or a file upload), not an EOF. You want something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while (!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals(""))
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Comment: As per https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html, "an HTTP/1.1 client MUST NOT preface or follow a request with an extra CRLF."

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer above (as I am not able to post comments yet), I'd like to add that some browsers like Opera (I guess it was what did it, or it was my ssl setup, I don't know) send an EOF. Even if not the case, you would like to prevent that in order for your server not to crash because of a NullPointerException.

To avoid that, just add the null test to your condition, like this:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && !inputLine.equals(""));
```