# Java Socket not receiving body of http request

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to read a HTTP request using only `Socket` and `BufferedReader` classes in Java. The problem is that I can't reach the body part of the request. The Buffered reader is giving me only the request line and the headers. Here is part of the code:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String comando = "";
        while((msgDoSocket = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            //telaOutput.adicionaFim(msgDoSocket);
            try {
                comando += msgDoSocket + " ";
                //System.out.println(comando);
                if(msgDoSocket.isEmpty()){
                    processaInput(comando);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Here is a WireShark capture showing that the POST body is being sent. My program is running on port 15000 and the data is just a string "teste12345". I'm using the app [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) from google chrome to send the requests.

[image]

I'm having exactly the same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11980255/2414842) thread but the solutions proposed there didn't work. The request still getting up to the last header and no more. Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Problem Solved!**
Following suggestion proposed on the answer, I changed the reading to:

```
reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


String comando = "";
while( (dt = reader.readByte()) >= 0){
  comando += dt;
  //... do the rest of the stuff
}
```

Reading it as binary made it possible to reach the `body` part of the request.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't read RFC 2616. The body of an HTTP request isn't required to consist of lines, and by default isn't terminated by end of stream.

Comment: A DataInputStream is not an appropriate solution. You want a plain BufferedInputStream.

Comment: Your problem is not solved. You still haven't implemented `Content-length`, and without that your solution  is incomplete. The .`DataInputStream` is not only inappropriate but unnecessary, and the `readByte()` loop you have coded is incorrect. It will stop at an arbitrary point in the input. This method does not return -1 at end of stream.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change my code to follow these instructions, @EJP and (at)bmargulies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm far from being a Java guru, but I bet that `readLine` only returns with results when it found a sequence of `\r\n`. since your body is not terminated with `\r\n` the method `readLine` never returns. try to manually add that character sequence to your body and see what happens, or alternatively, use the raw `InputStreamReader` to read the body as byte array.

never the less, you can't expect any http body to actually be a string. it can also be a binary sequence which knows nothing about `\r\n`.

Comment: To  be accurate, `readLine()` recognises any of the standard line terminations.